# Searching into a contact list

Tags: java, sorting, search, collections

I am performing search in a contact list using linear search with complexity \$O(n)\$. Please suggest me how to improve search strategy in my code.

```
public class ContactService {

    private Set<Contact> contacts;

    public ContactService() {
        this.contacts =  new TreeSet<>();
    }

    public void addContact(String name) {
        Contact contact = new Contact(name);
        contacts.add(contact);
    }

    public void searchContact(String searchStr) {
        System.out.println(contacts);
        for (Contact contact : contacts) {
            if (contact.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchStr)||(searchStr.contains(" ") && contact.getName().contains(searchStr))) {
                System.out.println(contact.getName());
            } else if (contact.getFirstName().toLowerCase().startsWith(searchStr) || contact.getLastName().toLowerCase().startsWith(searchStr)) {
                System.out.println(contact.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String name;

    public Contact(String name) {

        this.name = name;
        if (name.contains(" ")) {
            this.firstName = name.split("\\s+")[0];
            this.lastName = name.split("\\s+")[1];
        } else {
            this.firstName = name;
            this.lastName = "";
        }
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact{" + name + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Contact contact) {
        System.out.println("in compareto");
        return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(contact.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/31562) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 3):

Given what you seem to be trying to do, the best solution would be a full text search index.  [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) is an example of a Java library that handles that (and many other search related tasks).

Short of a tool like that, there's no easy way to do partial searches in better than linear time.  You are using a `TreeSet`, which can help with exact matches and prefix searches.  But you don't take advantage of that because you have it as a `Set` rather than a `NavigableSet`.  The latter interface includes methods that help with such searches.  In particular, `floor`, `higher`, and `subSet` are useful with a prefix search.  For example:

```
Contact needle = new Contact(searchStr);

StringBuilder roofName = new StringBuilder(searchStr.toLowerCase());
int lastIndex = roofName.length() - 1;
char last = roofName.charAt(lastIndex);
roofName.setCharAt(lastIndex, ++last);
Contact roof = new Contact(roofName.toString());

SortedSet<Contact> results = contacts.subSet(needle, roof);
```

Then `results` will hold all contacts with a `name` starting with `searchStr`.

Note that for easier searching, you may want to store a lower case version of `name` and compare on that.  So

```
public int compareTo(Contact contact) {
    System.out.println("in compareto");
    return this.lowerName.compareTo(contact.getLowerName());
}
```

Don't forget to change the constructor to set `lowerName`.

You can see that I already adjusted the search code above for that.  We need the `roofName` to be lower case because upper case letters are before lower case letters.  So if the string ends in a Z, we need it to be incremented to { rather than [.

Be careful about using a `Set`.  Note that it is quite possible to know two Joe Smiths.  Your current system can't handle that when using the `Comparator` to check for equality.